# What exactly is the shape of an atom as per modern physics?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

I am currently a student of grade $11$. I am pretty confused about how exactly the atom looks like? In books I have read till now used the electron orbiting model of atom. Some say there is "*electron cloud*" inside the atom. So can  someone clarify my doubt?

Comment: See [this](https://youtu.be/W2Xb2GFK2yc) amazing visual by minutephysics

Comment: Actually, I think it's a very good question and you're getting some good answers. The bottom line is that it's very difficult to even define the concept of "shape" for something which comprises components defined statistically.

Comment: @khaxan For those who like to skip sponsoring parts, note that there is also a bit of information in the last 15 seconds of the video.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The confusion arises because you have not yet learned much about quantum physics. Quantum physics is the most accurate and wide-ranging set of concepts and mathematical methods in physics, and it describes atoms very well. But quantum physics tells us that there is no single simple way to picture an electron.

An electron is not like a tiny particle moving from one place to another like a tiny planet on an orbit. But it is hard to say what it is like. This is why people bring in the word 'cloud'. This is because an electron is a bit like a charged cloud, smoothly filling a region of space around the atomic nucleus. The more precise statement is that the location and motion of the electron is fully described by a mathematical function called wavefunction. The modulus square of this function gives information about where the electron is. The way the function oscillates from place to place gives information about other properties such as energy and momentum.

If you take the squared wavefunction and multiply by the mass of an electron, you get the mass density. If instead you multiply by the charge of an electron, you get the charge density. It is usually this density which is plotted when you see pictures of what are called 'atomic orbitals'.

These orbitals are also like standing waves. But they are 3-dimensional ones. They oscillate with time and they typically have spatial oscillation in the radial direction and angular direction too. These 3-dimensional wavelike functions are, then, your best aid to visualizing the motion of an electron in an atom. But you should not entirely forget the orbit-like picture, because it reminds you that the electron is moving in and out and round and round, relative to the nucleus, by different amounts depending on which state of motion it is in.

Comment: But then doesnt whole textbook chemistry fall apart? It is based on the fact that electrons orbit around the nucleus(like planets in our solar system). For example : Ionic bond between $NaCl$ is due to $Na$ "$giving$" an electron to $Cl.$

Comment: @Aqua - I know as much as you do about these things, but one thing I've come to realize about just about any subject is - the _truth_ is almost always complicated and difficult to understand. And when you start to learn something (like in school), you start with a simplified approximation of that thing. Sometimes even a completely wrong approximation. And then, as you keep studying, you replace that approximation with a different (but more complicated) one, sometimes even multiple times. This is especially true of things involving quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Aqua Not exactly. The example of an ionic bond can be explained using this model as changes in those wavefunctions that describe the electrons of the sodium and chlorine atoms, and the changes _do_ involve that ‘extra’ electron being more likely to be near the chlorine atom. And even though the textbook description is not ‘correct’, it’s a useful abstraction because it explains most macro-scale (that is, larger than subatomic-scale) behavior accurately in a way that people can easily conceptualize without diverging _too_ much from what we believe to be the ‘correct’ model.

Comment: Dont look for a straight answer here, or by any physics professor, or any physics textbook. These people simply dont know. They will not admit it, no, not as long as the sun shines. They will talk about maths and quantum this and superposition that but you will get no answer.

Comment: @Aqua: All models are wrong. Some models are useful. To be more precise, some models are useful in some contexts.

Comment: Re textbook and chemistry. For ionic bonds the notion of an electron leaving one atom and going to another is a reasonable way to say what happens. The wavefunctions are indeed redistributed like that. And for covalent bonds you absolutely need quantum theory to make any sense of them. Now the wavefunction of one (or more) electrons extends between the atoms. More generally, the classical orbit picture cannot account for the *stability* of the situation. This is to do with emission of electromagnetic waves so beyond the entry-level discussion.

Comment: @Aqua - Some models capture more aspects of the real thing than others. A model is a representation, it's how you conceptualize something. Science often uses models formalized via math; this then allows scientists to predict things based on the model - and then experimentally check those predictions. If predictions match experimental results, then something about the model is right.  If after a while circumstances are found that don't match predictions, then you've discovered the conditions where the model is wrong - and you need a more encompassing model (that also explains the old results).

Comment: @Aqua - Sometimes, a simpler model/theory is more than adequate for many circumstances, so it's still used for problems that fall under those conditions, despite there being a more advanced, more complicated, more correct model/theory. A prime example of that is Newtonian gravity, which stops being correct in extreme environments, such as around black holes, where we need general relativity - a more correct theory of gravity. 
P.S. Jörg W. Mittag's "all models are wrong, some are useful" is a well known saying attributed to the statistician George Box.

Comment: @Aqua - Take a look at [this article](https://www.wikilectures.eu/w/Atomic_Models). On a related note - see also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQj0cxHJ4fc) (it talks about how these ideas are not introduced all at once in the education system, in this case, in the context of astronomy).

Comment: @Corbin That was a comment ofcourse. Not an answer. Thats why not written here. Why am I not posting an answer? because mainstream physics don't have an answer to that and this website is mainstream physics'. My answer would be downvoted and eventually deleted. I tried before. For anybody interested look for "miles mathis". I think its safe to write that in a comment, comments don't get downvoted. They do get deleted though. Lets see how this comment goes.

Comment: Aakaah, start a chat with me. We can talk about this more in private.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: way back in grad school, I took a stochastic modeling and control course (based on the (George) Box & Jenkins book, and given by one of Box's students). In addition to the "all models are wrong..." quote, a big part of the course was _the Principle of Parsimony_; if you have two models that are _close enough_ to matching your needs, the simpler model is the better one in this context.

Answer (score 17):

The electrons in an atom do, in a sense, orbit its nucleus. However, if you imagine this as being like planets orbiting a star then this picture is misleading.

One difference is that the shapes of the electrons orbits (called "orbitals") are more complicated than the elliptical shapes of planets' orbits. The shape of an electron's orbital depends on how many other electrons are in the atom and which layers or "shells" they occupy.

Another difference is that because of quantum mechanics we cannot say exactly where an electron is at any point in time. Instead, its orbital is a "cloud" or distribution of probabilities - we can say where the electron is most likely to be, but there is always a chance it could be in a different place.

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) illustrates the shapes of some electron orbitals.

Comment: IMO this is a better explanation for a high school student than the top answer.

Comment: NB: an "orbital" is very much not an "orbit". I would want to make it very clear that they aren't the same thing. Not least because orbitals are stationary states - which is about as unorbitlike as you can imagine. but also because electrons are not "in" orbitals unless you measure their energy (well, and not then, because atomic orbitals are approximations - but I think that's OK). Looking at pictures of the magnitude of an orbital is probably misleading.

Comment: Listen to Star Talk S14:EP39 from 32:35 to 33:15 [here](https://startalkmedia.com/show/cosmic-queries-mirror-mirror/) where Neil deGrasse Tyson explains that orbitals are not orbits.

Comment: @FrancisDavey Having been taught the Bohr model in school, that makes me wonder: If they are stationary "clouds", then the explanation of why they don't fall into the nucleus that I have been taught seems to be completely wrong: Energy levels are such that the electrons that occupy them form a standing wave, so don't lose energy due to radiating away EM waves. But if the electron, in some sense, is stationary, then why doesn't it fall?

Comment: "We can say where the electron is most likely to be, but there is always a chance it could be in a different place" If we can only talk in terms of probabilities then instead of making the claim that reality is probabilistic we should admit that our maths is incomplete and do not really explain what goes on. In other words, the maths is right some of the times, with some probability of being right. Whenever we look for an electron we do find it at one place, right? (contd.)

Comment: ...Did we ever observe same electron at two places? Do it even make sense? Obviously our maths do not match with our observation. So the fault is in maths. That should be said upfront and repeatedly, so one shouldn't question their observations, only their maths. Whenever we observe, in whatever way, we find a particle at only one place, any particle that be. Not just that but also in only one state. There is no superposition in reality. Superposition is a product of our maths, specifically our fourier transform, it has no resemblance with reality.

Comment: @Atif Reality (as in the reality of all the things that have been created using this "incomplete" maths, like e.g. your computer, your phone, or any other modern electronic device) respectfully disagrees with you and your favorite author who believes that π=4

Comment: Mathematicians - which includes physicists - dont produce anything other than equations. Its engineers that design products. Engineers use maths when it makes sense, not when it tell fairy tales such as quantum this and string that. Maths make sense when its process, the step by step working of it, matches with reality, not when only inputs and outputs match with reality. Its because stepwise matching tells mechanism and engineers need that, they have to you know actually produce something.

Comment: You haven't read him, right? You are parroting what others said. If you have read him you would know that pi = 4 thing is for kinematics only, not geometry. Geometry is static, not changing, no time dimension. Also, do science, experiment, find the value yourself (see his experiment). There are no favourites in science, only in politics, dont do politics.

Comment: @kutschkem - there are different ways of talking about what is essentially the same mathematics (and same observable results), which in the case of quantum mechanics, seem to get people quite agitated, so I am cautious about digging in further. In short, the usual way of discussing the atom does not have moving electrons (quantum particles have no momentum until you observe them). If you favour an interpretation in which the electrons "move", then there will be an answer (several of them in fact).

Comment: @Atif Hopeless. This is my last comment, but I *am* an engineer and I do my work pretty successfully assuming that π≠4. I have never met a successful engineer believing in alternative physics created by a self-proclaimed universal genius.

Comment: @das I am a Computer Engineer. I never have to use derivations in my 19 years of experience. Do it imply that derivation is wrong? A Civil Engineer may never have to use derivation, integration. So go for an Electronics Engineer. You just don't work in rotational kinematics or use precalculated logs or have other formulae in usage that cover that. To actually test something scientifically you have to do an experiment. Did you do any? Did you even do an observation by plugging correct value of Pi in kinematics problems? Note that the claim is about kinematics, not geometry which is static.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hard question to answer, as we really only have mathematical formulas, and can only create illustrations that emulate some aspects of the math (but not all).

Personally, I like to visualize electrons in an atom as standing waves around the nucleus, like [this experiment](https://youtu.be/zZ5ww6aYAZ8).

When they are interacting with photons or otherwise participating in collisions, I picture it as a localized point particle (billiard ball).

I'm not claiming this is the most rigorously accurate approach possible, but it helps me and I think tracks reasonably well with the math.

Visuals are important to aid our understanding and calculation, and will never encompass the full reality.

Additional Note: although the various orbitals take a variety of mode shapes, the outermost orbital in any free atom is the *s* orbital, which is *spherical*.  So the "shape" determining its collisions and interactions with other atoms (e.g. in a noble gas like Helium or Argon, or a gas of atomic hydrogen) is spherical.  Molecules on the other hand like $\mathrm{H}_2$ or benzene in gaseous form can take on elliptical or more complex shapes.  And condensed matter like liquid or solid is another topic entirely.

Comment: Personally, I put my trust in the Wigner representation of QM. When you apply it to the Hydrogen ground syate, you get a simple expression for e.g. the kinetic energy in the $x$ direction. It shows you that along the $x$ axis there is no contribution. Momentum and position are orthogonal. In other words: the electron rotates around the nucleus. Trivial? No, not at all.